# A Sudoku With A Trick

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

[image: This is a Sudoku puzzle created by the puzzle maker Shye. It has a very clever and ingenious trick to solve it.]

- Normal Sudoku rules apply in this puzzle.
- This is an incredibly difficult puzzle to solve and has a
  very clever and ingenious trick in it.
- I request solvers to show their work at different stages of the puzzle (as they see fit).

EDIT 1 - Partial Answers are encouraged even if you have done only the Naked Singles.

---

<sub>This puzzle is not my own. Proper attribution will be provided once the puzzle is solved. This is because the page where I saw this puzzle also has its solution in it. For some partial attribution, I have been told that this puzzle was created by the puzzle maker *Shye*.</sub>

Comment: Given that with the information you have provided (ie the creator) I can easily find (took me 15 seconds) the puzzle's posting on logicmasters germany here: https://logic-masters.de/Raetselportal/Raetsel/zeigen.php?id=0006MT where it doesn't have a solution as far as I can see I am not sure why you don't just provide that link? Besides, if people want to cheat and look at solutions then that's on them really...

Comment: Other than perhaps being a difficult sudoku, is there actually any "trick" involved?  Because I plugged this into a sudoku solver and it quickly spit out the solution, leading me to believe there's nothing especially interesting about the puzzle.

Comment: @SQLnoob does your solver use only human-like deduction? Because solving a sudoku automatically using brute-force and backtracking is a trivial task for a computer, but that's not what a human would do. I tried a little bit to solve this sudoku but I couldn't get much further apart from writing down ~10 numbers using some basic deduction rules.

Comment: Having watched the solve of this on Cracking The Cryptic youtube channel there is a very nice trick in it and they titled their video "Classic Sudoku: A new incredible trick" - given how much sudoku they do I assume therefore that this trick is a bit out of the ordinary.

Comment: @melfnt all i mean is that this is essentially just a regular sudoku.  it might be harder than your average puzzle but there's no "trick" to it.  you'd solve it the same way you solve every other normal sudoku.  (human-like deduction as it applies to sudoku is effectively just slightly-refined brute force anyway!)

Comment: @Chris that seems to be a big spoiler.

Comment: @KabirKanhaArora: Not sure what I said that spoiled anything? The link to logic masters germany is just the same puzzle as far as I can see and saying that it was solved on Cracking The Cryptic channel doesn't spoil anything. Sure, people can go there and look at a full solve but we're not children. If somebody wants to look at the solution they can. If they don't want spoilers they just don't go there... Unless you think me saying "its a nice trick" is a spoiler in which case I would argue that it is no more of a spoiler than the original question...

Comment: @SQLnoob  "you'd solve it the same way you solve every other normal sudoku" did you mean by only using some of the tecniques listed [here](https://sudopedia.org/wiki/Solving_Techniques)? I tried and I failed, hence there must be some "trick". Also, human-like deduction is not slightly-refined brute force, they are two different algorithms. Anyway I won't comment further, not here nor on the answer below since it's clear that neither of us is going to change their mind. Sorry

Comment: @melfnt yes, i meant using the same techniques used to solve every other sudoku ever invented.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>     1    .   1   2   |   .   7   .   |   3   5   .
>     2    3   .   .   |   2   .   1   |   4   .   7
>     3    4   .   .   |   5   .   .   |   .   1   6
>          ------------+---------------+------------
>     4    2   .   .   |   .   .   .   |   .   7   .
>     5    1   6   .   |   .   8   .   |   .   .   2
>     6    .   4   8   |   .   .   .   |   6   3   .
>          ------------+---------------+------------
>     7    .   .   .   |   8   .   .   |   .   .   4
>     8    .   .   .   |   1   5   .   |   .   .   3
>     9    .   .   .   |   .   4   3   |   1   2   .
>
>
>          a   b   c       d   e   f       g   h   i
> ```

New entries are marked by `*`

> ```
>     1    .   1   2   |   .   7   .   |   3   5   .
>     2    3   .   .   |   2   .   1   |   4   .   7
>     3    4   .   .   |   5  *3   .   |  *2   1   6
>          ------------+---------------+------------
>     4    2   .   .   |   .   .   .   |   .   7   .
>     5    1   6   .   |   .   8   .   |   .  *4   2
>     6    .   4   8   |   .   .   .   |   6   3   .
>          ------------+---------------+------------
>     7    .  *3  *1   |   8   .   .   |   .   .   4
>     8    .  *2  *4   |   1   5   .   |   .   .   3
>     9    .   .   .   |   .   4   3   |   1   2   .
>
>
>          a   b   c       d   e   f       g   h   i
> ```

Multi-digit entries are understood to show all that is not ruled out yet.

> ```
>     1    .   1   2   |   .   7   .   |   3   5 *89
>     2    3   .   .   |   2  *69  1   |   4 *89   7
>     3    4   .   .   |   5   3   .   |   2   1   6
>          ------------+---------------+------------
>     4    2   .   .   |   .   .   .   |   .   7   .
>     5    1   6   .   |   .   8   .   |   .   4   2
>     6    .   4   8   |   .   .   .   |   6   3   .
>          ------------+---------------+------------
>     7    .   3   1   |   8   .   .   |   .   .   4
>     8    .   2   4   |   1   5   .   |   .   .   3
>     9    .   .   .   |   .   4   3   |   1   2   .
>
>
>          a   b   c       d   e   f       g   h   i
> ```

> if e2 = 6 must have a1 = 6
>     if e2 = 9 cannot have a1 = 9
>     therefore never a1 = 9, leaving 68
>
> ```
>     1   *68  1   2   |   .   7   .   |   3   5  89
>     2    3   .   .   |   2  69   1   |   4  89   7
>     3    4   .   .   |   5   3   .   |   2   1   6
>          ------------+---------------+------------
>     4    2   .   .   |   .   .   .   |   .   7   .
>     5    1   6   .   |   .   8   .   |   .   4   2
>     6    .   4   8   |   .   .   .   |   6   3   .
>          ------------+---------------+------------
>     7    .   3   1   |   8   .   .   |   .   .   4
>     8    .   2   4   |   1   5   .   |   .   .   3
>     9    .   .   .   |   .   4   3   |   1   2   .
>
>
>          a   b   c       d   e   f       g   h   i
> ```

Very clever and ingenious trick / shameless cheat:

> If a1 = 8 then b9 = 8, h2 = 8, g8 = 8, i4 = 8
>     the last forces e4 = 1 and we see that d1,f1,d4,f4 must be 2x4 + 2x6
>     If we are allowed to use the assumption that the puzzle has a unique
>     solution then this is a contradiction
>     Therefore a1 = 6

> ```
>     1   *6   1   2   |  *4   7  *89  |   3   5  89
>     2    3   .   .   |   2  *6   1   |   4  89   7
>     3    4   .   .   |   5   3  *89  |   2   1   6
>          ------------+---------------+------------
>     4    2   .   .   |  *6   .  *4   |   .   7   .
>     5    1   6   .   |   .   8   .   |   .   4   2
>     6    .   4   8   |   .   .   .   |   6   3   .
>          ------------+---------------+------------
>     7    .   3   1   |   8   .   .   |   .   .   4
>     8    .   2   4   |   1   5   .   |   .   .   3
>     9    .   .  *6   |   .   4   3   |   1   2   .
>
>
>          a   b   c       d   e   f       g   h   i
> ```

> If f5 = 7 must have a6 = 7 and d9 = 7
>     leaving no room for 7 in bottom left box
>     Therefore f5 != 7 leaving 5
>
>     The rest is routine

> ```
>     1    6   1   2   |   4   7  *9   |   3   5  *8
>     2    3  *8  *5   |   2   6   1   |   4  *9   7
>     3    4  *7  *9   |   5   3  *8   |   2   1   6
>          ------------+---------------+------------
>     4    2  *9  *3   |   6  *1   4   |  *8   7  *5
>     5    1   6  *7   |  *3   8  *5   |  *9   4   2
>     6   *5   4   8   |  *9  *2  *7   |   6   3  *1
>          ------------+---------------+------------
>     7   *7   3   1   |   8  *9  *2   |  *5  *6   4
>     8   *9   2   4   |   1   5  *6   |  *7  *8   3
>     9   *8  *5   6   |  *7   4   3   |   1   2  *9
>
>
>          a   b   c       d   e   f       g   h   i
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I must have missed the trick somehow. You can fill in a few 1/2/3/4s straight away. After that there are only two spaces left in the top right, which are 8/9 in some order. I tried the one that seemed to give most information, hoping to get a contradiction and eliminate it. After that I just followed my nose - you can get the rest of the 8s, then the 6s and a couple of 5s, then that gives you the 7 in the bottom right which starts another chain of deductions. Somewhat to my surprise, I didn't get a contradiction but a solution.

[image]

Comment: Having watched the video of the solution another commenter posted, I can confirm there's no trick. It's just a sudoku.

Comment: @SQLnoob the problem is the followed-my-nose part, also known as "guessing"  or "brute forcing". The trick is how to find this very same solution using only logical deduction steps.

Comment: Trying one possibility and hoping to find a contradiction is a form of bifurcation which is strongly avoided in a proper logical-deduction & grid-deduction setting. I'm pretty sure finding a smart argument i.e. why the other possibility is wrong without bifurcation, is what this question intended to.

Comment: @melfnt the problem is that the logical deduction steps used in sudoku all amount to the same thing as following your nose - "if this cell was X, then this other cell would have to be Y, but it can't be Y so therefore this cell isn't X" etc.  all sudoku "tricks" are just variants of the same exact thing.

Comment: @melfnt no, the "followed my nose" part doesn't involve any guessing. The only guess I made was putting 8 in the extreme top right. Everything else is a series of straightforward deductions from that one assumption.

Comment: @SQLnoob True that logical deduction steps are somewhat finding an contradiction and such, but to some extent. I love to link this blogpost by Thomas Snyder (a.k.a Dr Sudoku): https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/2013/03/ask-dr-sudoku-12-the-line-must-be-drawn-here/ to define the "limit" of trial-and-error. In short, here is his quote: "When I can solve a puzzle in ink, without erasures, with all deductions either positive or negative coming from visualization in my head and not making scratch-work on the paper, the puzzle is solvable by logic."

Comment: @athin that sounds like a limit of his working memory, not logic. he even says "If you’ve never reasoned out before why a 7 cannot go into R8C2, this may feel like guesswork. The Y-wing step, while mathematically solid in a sudoku language of strong and weak links, feels like guesswork until you get used to seeing it."  that's what all sudoku "techniques" are, they're just variants of "if this cell is an X then this other cell can't be a Y..." etc.  there's nothing fundamentally different between "guessing" that a cell is a 7 and seeing what happens, and "using a Y-wing" or whatever.

Comment: in fact the "very clever and ingenious trick" described in loopy's solution posted here says (values removed so as not to spoil it): "if cell1 = value then cell2 = value, cell3 = value, cell4 = value, cell5 = value the last forces cell6 = value and we see that cell6, cell7, cell8, cell9 must be something and something_else if we are allowed to use the assumption that the puzzle has a unique solution then this is a contradiction.  Therefore cell1 = other_value."  that's not a trick, that's essentially every sudoku technique ever.

Comment: @SQLnoob Agreed to that actually! I'm personally not a sudoku-person, thus for me the technique like wings etc. felt a bit bashy (?) and more towards a pattern recognition. Thus here is my personal thought for this: if someone asked you to solve it while explaining the reasoning path to them, if at some point you hesitated and they are not convinced enough, then it's an indication of trial-and-error. Sudoku is not my cup of tea, thus here I'm explaining in a general grid-puzzle context. In fact, I can't even judge whether the technique by loopy walt is clever or not, so I'm leaving it to pros.

Comment: @SQLnoob I'm not a sudoku person, but I don't see why it's legitimate to assume the solution is unique, since that is not stated in OP. Do "normal sudoku rules" imply this? A quick google search for that term suggests not.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime i'm fairly sure normal sudoku rules imply a single unique solution.

Comment: @SQLnoob https://sudopedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_Controversy

Comment: Good solution. However, this is basically a trial and error approach and luckily for you it worked out. The solution has a logical path to it.

Comment: This answer uses similar assumption as loopy's though. If you assume uniqueness, once you found a solution by assuming a certain value, then the other value must have led to contradiction even though we haven't explored that yet.

Comment: @justhalf It depends on your perspective. Is the aim to find *a* solution, or to find *all* solutions? I've only done the former.

Comment: What I meant is that, you can extend your answer that currently finds one solution by happenstance into an answer that finds all solution by using the assumption that there is a unique solution, an assumption that loopy used in their answer too. (also, my previous comment was directed to Sid, not to you, sorry if that wasn't clear)